# How to find strings in HTML using a regular expression?

Tags: html, regex, pcre

We are trying to look for regex in a html source code. We need to mark a special expression, which is "SRV" in our case.

The text looks like:

```
<p><b>Cancelled:</b></p>

<p><b>Failed:</b></p>
SRV

<p><b>Successful:</b><br>
SRV-LOC-APP01, SRV-LOC-APP02, SRV-LOC-BCK01, SRV-LOC-DC01, SRV-LOC-PHD02,
SRV-LOC-PRT01, SRV-LOC-SHR01, SRV-LOC-SQL01, SRV-LOC-SQL02, SRV-LOC-SYS01,
SRV-LOC-VIR01, WKS-LOC-008 </p>

<p><b>Incomplete:</b></p>

<p><b>Not Attempted:</b></p>
```

Our regex is :

```
((?s)(?<=Failed:).*(?=Successful))
```

This marks all between Failed:  and Successful.

But we need that ONLY `SRV` is marked, if it is not empty.  If there is no `SRV` listed nothing should be marked.

Comment: Is this necessarily dependent on HTML? It could be any text?

Comment: Just add .*SRV.*

Comment: If you can use ordinary code, it looks like each section is in its own paragraph tag. You could retrieve each one, and then do your regex in the text contents. That would simplify your expression.

Comment: Hi, it could be any text. Just adding .*SRV.* does not change our result. We need that SRV is marked as a hit, when it is listed under Failed and not all with whitespace, bold etc.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `(?s)Failed:(?>.*?\KSRV)(?=.*?Successful:)`